# How to integrate already SPA project to laravel Inertia?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I've downloaded React dashboard app and I want to use it inside my laravel inertia application.
I got confused how to merge their files together.
React components should be inside resources/js/Pages in laravel Inertia.
I got confused how to merge react app with laravel inertia app
Here are images of files for each of them.

[image: image of laravel inertia React components]
[image: image of SPA files]

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Your jsx templates go in the resources/js/Pages folder. You build your routes in the routes/web.php, for example:

```
  Route::get('dashboard', [UserController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
```

Make sure to include any used Controllers at the top of web.php:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
```

The controllers, which you can create using the artisan command at the command line in terminal or other cli:

```
php artisan make:controller HomeController
```

This creates the file in app\Http\Controllers, for example HomeController to return the jsx via Inertia, including any data loaded via Eloquent or otherwise:

```
public function dashboard() {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
      'items'      => $items
    ]);
}
```

Make sure your controller uses Inertia (at the top):

```
use Inertia\Inertia;
```

This assumes you created the project with Inertia using React so you have the proper blade templates which handle the SPA build. You'll also need to be sure at command line you run:

```
npm install
npm run dev (or npm run build for production)
```

The latest Laravel uses vite and tailwind quite effectively (older version used/suggested webpack.

Recently I've found Laravel Herd with DBngin and TablePlus as a great combination for anyone needing a local dev environment.